# Unable to access Samba folder from Windows (Using Raspberry Pi XMBC as a Samba Server)

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, samba

Can someone explain what I am getting an access denied message when I try accessing the folders via Windows 8

```
     [global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    usershare allow guests = yes
    security=share
   #security=user
    follow symlinks = yes
    wide links = no
    unix extensions = no
    lock directory = /var/cache/samba
  realm = localdomain
  server role = domain controller
[pi]
    browsable = yes
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    path = /home/pi
    #force user = pi (no longer needed)
[devices]
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    writable = yes
    path = /media
[Toshiba HDD]
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    writable = yes
    path = /ToshibaHDD
```

Answer (score -1):

That may depend on the directory and file rights. If the us who runs smb have no access rights, you can't read or write files. You can find out file permissions with ls -la you will also see owner and owner group.
You can try to set read and write permissions for all (chmod 777 directory -R). If this was the problem, then you should give read and write permissions only to the user that runs smb. Set permissions for all back to 0 (770) because of security reasons.

[Here you find a tutorial on set up samba for Rasapberry Pi.](http://developer-blog.net/en/hardware-2/xbmc-turns-you-raspberry-pi-into-a-media-server/#more-432)